# Java Map question

Tags: java, data-structures

I have one Map that contains some names and numbers

```
Map<String,Integer> abc = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

It works fine. I can put some values in it but when I call it in different class it gives me wrong order. For example:

I putted

```
abc.put("a",1);
abc.put("b",5);
abc.put("c",3);

    Iterator<String> iter = abc.keySet().iterator();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {

        String name = iter.next();
        System.out.println(name);
    }
```

some time it returns the order (b,a,c) and some time (a,c,b).

What is wrong with it? Is there any step that I am missing when I call this map?

Edit:
I changed to HashMap and result is still same

Comment: please show us some code how you read the list, i.e. check the order of the entries

Comment: I added the excerpt of the code

Comment: Using your above code, the order of the items **will always be the same** on the same JVM. It isn’t well-defined but it doesn’t miraculously change between two runs, either. So you’re not telling us the whole story.

Comment: so, you want to preserve the insertion order? Or you want to have consistent order?

Comment: @Konrad: that's not necessarily true. It would be a perfectly correct for an implementation to have some sort of additional factor in the hash function that is different for each instance.

Comment: @Michael: it may be technically correct due to the specifications but it doesn’t happen in practice, ever (because this implementation would be nonsensical and incur a useless runtime overhead). So I’m concluding that there must be more, which may be causing the actual problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing that's wrong is your expectations. The `Map` interface makes no guarantees about iteration order, and the `HashMap` implementation is based on hash functions which means the iteration order is basically random, and will sometimes change completely when new elements are added.

If you want a specific iteration order, you have thee options:

- The `SortedMap` interfaces with its `TreeMap` implementation - these guarantee an iteration order according to the natural ordering of the keys (or an ordering imposed by a `Comparator` instance)
- The `LinkedHashMap` class iterates in the order the elements were added to the map.
- Use a `List` instead of a `Map` - this has a well-defined iteration order that you can influence in detail.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more why the `a, b, c` order expectation is wrong on a `TreeMap`?

Comment: @khachik: Assuming that no custom comparator is used, the expectation is correct for `TreeMap` - but not for `HashMap` or the `Map` interface in general. And we don't know whether the OP expects that as natural ordering of the keys or as insertion order.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

Comment: Thanks but LinkedHashMap is slowers than HashMap in performance :( and I am touchy about performance

Comment: @user552961: Touchy as in "I've profiled the program and know that iterating over this map is my bottleneck", or touchy as in "I optimize prematurely for no good reason"?

Comment: Why do you think it is slower? On which operation? On `get(..)` it is `O(1)`. For insertion, and space - it is a price you have to pay in order to preserve order.

Comment: Either you need to preserve order or you don't.  The cost of using LinekdHashMap over HashMap is so small, I am will to bet you couldn't measure the difference. (Or even give me a figure as to what difference is important to you)  Don't worry about performance until you have a working system IMHO.

Comment: For the example given either both will take under 500 ns.  If performance is much more critical to you I would suggest you avoid using either and use another collection type customized to your specific needs.

Comment: @Falmarri, a bold claim.  Having designed low latency systems using Java, I think you can achieve more than you can with other languages given a real project with serious time restraints. Given the OP is confused about why different collections have keys in different orders, I suspect there are performance issues which are beyond the scope of the OP's job.

Answer (score 0):

A TreeMap will always have keys in their natural order (unless you provide a comparator)  If you are seeing the order any differently it will be the way you are looking at the map and what you are doing with it.  If in doubt, use a debugger and you will see the order is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to get map values in the same order you used to insert them use `LinkedHashMap` instead.

Comment: I think the question is why it is printed in different order.